# Isolate scope in reusable angular direcives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive : myContent

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule').directive('myContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myContent.html',

    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.selectedContents = {
        priceOrTransactionOption : null,
        yearlyOrMonthly : 'Yearly',
        contentIndicator : null
      };
      $scope.comboContent = {
        priceOrTransactionOption : ['By Price Range', 'By Transactions'],
        yearlyOrMonthly : ['Yearly', 'Monthly'],
        contentIndicator : ['Active configuration', 'Next Configuration']
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'myContentCtrl'
  };
});
```

And I'm using this same directive in multiple places :

```
<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
      <my-content></my-content>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
     <my-content></my-content>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
     <my-content></my-content>
</div>
```

And my html page for the directive (myContent.html) is having some data with :

```
<div class="row no-left-padding">
    <div class="col-lg-3 no-left-padding">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedContent.priceOrTransactionOption"
                ng-options="keyOption as keyOption for keyOption in comboContent.priceOrTransactionOption">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 no-left-padding">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedContent.yearlyOrMonthly" ng-disabled = "true"
                ng-options="interval as interval for interval in comboContent.yearlyOrMonthly">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 no-left-padding">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedContent.contentIndicator"
                ng-options="indicator as indicator for indicator in comboContent.contentIndicator">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But my problem is, when ever I'm changing the model in one directive, it reflects in each directives.

How can I use the same directive, and map each with different models?

I had tried with wadding one attribute to my custom directive:

```
<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
      <my-content category="type1"></my-content>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
     <my-content category="type2"></my-content>
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
     <my-content category="type3"></my-content>
</div>
```

But still I'm confused with where should I map the category for getting isolated object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add Isolated scope to your directive. This effectively allows it to have its own set of properties:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
    scope: { 
         category:'='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.selectedContents = {
        priceOrTransactionOption : null,
        yearlyOrMonthly : 'Yearly',
        contentIndicator : null
      };
      $scope.comboContent = {
        priceOrTransactionOption : ['By Price Range', 'By Transactions'],
        yearlyOrMonthly : ['Yearly', 'Monthly'],
        contentIndicator : ['Active configuration', 'Next Configuration']
      };
    },
    controllerAs: 'myContentCtrl'
  };
});
```

You can then use your example above:

```
<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
      <my-content category="type1"></my-content>
</div>
```

And each one will work individually.

Take note though, when you add your properties of the isolated scope binding '='. There are a number of different types, '@', '=' and '&' as well as optional arguments. The naming of your scope property uses snake case. Rather than me giving you a full explanation, read the [Angular developers guide on isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: But the combo change is reflecting in each UI componets, it is not cosidering the isolated scope. Did I missed any mapping?

Comment: When you say the combo change is reflected, i'm not sure what you mean? I can't actually see how you are using the category property in your code. Perhaps update the question to show how you are using  category="typexx" ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I will update my code in plunker, and share with you.

Comment: I just noticed in your html page you have an unexpected = sign after the "=, ng-model="=selectedContent.yearlyOrMonthly". Unsure if this is causing your problem?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo. in original code it is not there.

Comment: yeah.. I got it. :) 
when i copied the code to plunker, got noticed i was using $scope instead of scope. That was the mistake. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your directive definition:

```
restrict: 'E',
scope: {},
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I had tried scope: {}, but I'm not sure about the implementaion. I'm entirely new to angular js. Could you pls help me with a sample code?

Comment: You don't need to do anything else. Just add the scope: {} line under the restrict: 'E', line as show in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you want is to return `selectedContents` for each instance of the directive.  To do this, you would use angular two way binding to create a link between your directive and the page content.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myContent.html',
    scope: {
      selectedContents: '='  
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.selectedContents = {
        priceOrTransactionOption : null,
        yearlyOrMonthly : 'Yearly',
        contentIndicator : null
      };
....
```

now, you can refer to the `selectedContents` as a parameter on the directive.

```
<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
      <my-content selectedContents="someObject.selectedContents"></my-content>
</div>
<div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
      <my-content selectedContents="someOtherObject.selectedContents"></my-content>
</div>
```